# How to add more than one comment box in PHP using PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html, phpmyadmin

I am using PHPMyAdmin to construct a table like a comment box. The file I used is in PHP Script and I set up the 'id', 'name', and 'comment' values for the feedback/comment form using PHPMyAdmin. I was thrilled to see when I input the name and comment, it worked. Afterwards, it showed up on the bottom. Then, when I tried adding a second comment, it isn't stored anywhere on the page or the database table. It only keeps the first comment I put in and the second comment is no where to be found. I assume it has something to do with the limit of rows, but I looked in PHPMyAdmin and saw the LIMIT 0,30 which means it can take 30 comments. What am I missing here?

[image: IMG of my commenttable]
[image: IMG of commenttable attributes]

PHPMyAdmin settings for 'commenttable':

```
 SELECT *
 FROM `commenttable`
 LIMIT 0 , 30!
```

PHP Code:

```
           <section>
                <h1 id="theme"><span class="initial">F</span>eedback</h1>
                <div id="message">
                <!--Place content here-->
                <?php
                mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
                mysql_select_db("database");
                $name=$_POST['name'];
                $comment=$_POST['comment'];
                $submit=$_POST['submit'];

                $dbLink = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
                    mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8", $dbLink);
                    mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8", $dbLink);

                if($submit)
                {
                    if($name&&$comment)
                    {
                        $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO commenttable (name,comment) VALUES ('$name','$comment') ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "please fill out all fields";
                    }
                }
                ?>

                <div id="feedback_form">
                    <form action="feedbacktest.php" method="POST">
                        <table>
                        <tr><td>Name: <input type="text" name="name"/></td></tr>
                        <tr><td colspan="2">Comment: </td></tr>
                        <tr><td colspan="5"><textarea name="comment" rows="6" cols="30"></textarea></td></tr>
                        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment" style="cursor:pointer;"></td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <?php
                $dbLink = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
                    mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $dbLink);
                    mb_language('uni');
                    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

                $getquery=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM commenttable ORDER BY id DESC");
                while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))
                {
                    $id=$rows['id'];
                    $name=$rows['name'];
                    $comment=$rows['comment'];
                    echo $name . '<br/>' . '<br/>' . $comment . '<br/>' . '<br/>' . '<hr size="1"/>';
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Since you don't seem to quite get how PHPMyAdmin works I'm gonna ask the dumb question of did you refresh your query after adding your new comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the attribute `auto_increment` to the field `id`. Otherwise, all entries will get the same identifier and your script will not retrieve it from the database as you are using

```
$getquery=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM commenttable ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Check out

```
$getquery=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM commenttable");
```

Does your new entry show up?

**Question regarding `LIMIT 0 , 30`**

This part of the query is only used to limit the number of returned rows to 30. This has nothing to do with how many entries your database can store. For more information see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html.

Comment: I see! Thanks. I modified the attribute to auto_increment and it's working now.

Comment: Glad I could help. To help others, you can *accept* my answer to mark this question as "solved".